# authentification with spring security and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing spring security with a spring boot-angular application. In my user controller, I have mapped a method on the following url: /api/user/login to connect the user, fetch the User information, identify the user and check he is registered in the data base. When I launch the angular application, , the  url: http://localhost:8080/api/user/login  is triggered with a 405 status error. I have several question

1) is it normal that the url : http://localhost:8080/api/user/login, be triggered at the start ? I don't understand why. I want the connection of a user be dedicated to a form pop up (for which the http://localhost:8080/api/user/login url is triggered)

2) if it is normal, what is the purpose of such an url and how have I to implement the end point controller with this url ?

3) in my angular application, I set up the proxy.config.json as the following

```
{
  "/api/*": {

    "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8080
     },
    "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

to redirect each localhost:42OO/api to localhost:8080/api. For that purpose, on the front end part, I launch the application with "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json" command.

When "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login" is triggered, I have the following error message:

```
    Blocage d’une requête multiorigines (Cross-Origin Request) : la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur http://localhost:8080/api/user/login. Raison : l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » est manquant.
Blocking of a multi-origin request (Cross-Origin Request): the "Same Origin" policy does not allow consulting the remote resource located on http: // localhost: 8080 / api / user / login. Reason: The CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing.
```

So, how to takle this ?

Here is the configuration for the spring security concerns

File WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.MyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http         
        .headers()
         .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
         .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
           .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/api/user/login")
               .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
//               .failureUrl("/login?error")
               .failureUrl("/")
               .permitAll()
               .and()
           .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
//            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .deleteCookies("my-remember-me-cookie")
               .permitAll()
               .and()
            .rememberMe()
             //.key("my-secure-key")
             .rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me-cookie")
             .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
             .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
             .and()
           .exceptionHandling()
           .and()
           .csrf().disable();
    }

    PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(){
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

}
```

The user controller UserController.java

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/user"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody UserDTO login(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
        String message = userService.checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(userDTO);
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            userDTO = userService.findByEmailAndPassword(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
            userDTO.setPassword("");
        } else {
            userDTO.setMessage(message);
        }
        return userDTO;
    }
```

The InitialDataLoader.java file

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.Privilege;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.Role;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.PrivilegeRepository;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.UserRepository;

@Component
public class InitialDataLoader implements
  ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    boolean alreadySetup = false;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (alreadySetup)
            return;
        Privilege readPrivilege
          = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("READ_PRIVILEGE");
        Privilege writePrivilege
          = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("WRITE_PRIVILEGE");

        List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = Arrays.asList(
          readPrivilege, writePrivilege);        
        createRoleIfNotFound("ADMIN", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("LOUEUR", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ACHETER", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("DEPOSE_LOUER", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("DEPOSE_ACHETER", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("AGENCE", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("PROMOTEUR", adminPrivileges);



        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName("ADMIN");

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail("flamant@club-internet.fr");
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setGender("M");
            user.setFirstName("adminFirstName");
            user.setLastName("adminLastName");
            user.setRaisonSociale("adminLastName");
            user.setName("PARTICULIER");
            user.setLastName("adminLastName");
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("adminPassword"));
            user.setEmail("flamant@club-internet.fr");
            user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));
            user.setEnabled(true);
            user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
            user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
            user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }

        alreadySetup = true;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(String name) {

        Privilege privilege = privilegeRepository.findByName(name);
        if (privilege == null) {
            privilege = new Privilege(name);
            privilegeRepository.save(privilege);
        }
        return privilege;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Role createRoleIfNotFound(
      String name, Collection<Privilege> privileges) {

        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(name);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new Role(name);
            role.setPrivileges(privileges);
            roleRepository.save(role);
        }
        return role;
    }
}
```

The UserDetailsService implementation:

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.Privilege;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.Role;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.UserRepository;

@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //@Autowired
    //private IUserService service;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
              " ", " ", true, true, true, true, 
              (Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>) getAuthorities(Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"))));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
          user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(), user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), 
          user.isAccountNonLocked(), getRolesAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getRolesAuthorities(
              Collection<Role> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role :roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(
      Collection<Role> roles) {

        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles) {

        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role : roles) {
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for (Privilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: answer added for CORS. For other problem, share your Angular code please (why URL is fetched at start). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At least, to go forward, you should enable `CORS` on your backend. 
Angular app is served at `http://localhost:4200` and browser refuses to make request to another domain (in this case `http://localhost:8080`).
[More information on CORS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

So, you should whitelist your **front-end** url on your **backend** app.

You can easily do that with Spring Boot by adding some lines in your `Application` class :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...

    /**
     * CORS configuration
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200"
                )
                .allowedMethods(
                        "GET",
                        "PUT",
                        "POST",
                        "DELETE",
                        "PATCH",
                        "OPTIONS"
                );
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Why we need `@Configuration` if you already added `@SpringBootApplication` in your main class.?

Comment: More on this annotation here.. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation

Answer (score 0):

gnana and Arpit and thank you for your answer.

Considering the issue on CORS, I have added the code you gave me and it works. But can you explain me the difference between your solution (SOLUTION1) and (SOLUTION2 :) the fact that I added the file
proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {

    "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8080
     },
    "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

and launched the front part with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

With SOLUTION2, every request that are launched in the front end part (that is http://localhost:4200) are translated to  http://localhost:8080 and what about the following request http://localhost:8080/api/user/login that is automatically trigerred at the start of the angular application

With your solution (SOLUTION1) you allow request such as http://localhost:4200 (but in fact with SOLUTION2 still running these request are translated in the front end part into http://localhost:8080) and at the same time the back end take in charge the request http://localhost:8080/api/user/login that is triggered when I run for the first time the angular application (the home page of the application which does not include the login page (the later is displayed when I click on a button))

If you can give me some explanation, thank you

Considering the other questions I ask on the first post, I investigated further

I don't know why the http://localhost:8080/api/user/login request is triggered when I run the home page of the front end application. Thierry suggested to share my angular code, but I am not convinced that it will help: the only request that provide login on the angular part is not triggered. I checked it. The authentication process to login in the front end part is based upon a form that appear (pop up) when clicking on a button. Thierry, could you please suggest me which part of the angular app you want me to share. Thank you

What I can tell you is when I have the following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/user"})
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login",
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody UserDTO login(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
    String message = userService.checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(userDTO);
    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        userDTO = userService.findByEmailAndPassword(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
        userDTO.setPassword("");
    } else {
        userDTO.setMessage(message);
    }
    return userDTO;
}
```

The following url: http://localhost:8080/api/user/login is triggered (why ? there is no reason I can see, the only thing I can say is that it dépends on the following code on back

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http         
        .headers()
         .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
         .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
           .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/api/user/login")
               .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
//               .failureUrl("/login?error")
               .failureUrl("/")
               .permitAll()
```

When I inspect Firebug, I have the following header

```
URL de la requête : http://localhost:8080/api/user/login
Méthode de la requête : GET
Adresse distante : 127.0.0.1:8080
Code d’état :405
```

and the following response

```
timestamp   2020-03-11T11:09:05.482+0000
status  405
error   Method Not Allowed
message Request method 'GET' not supported
path    /api/user/login
```

This response is what is expected because it is mapped to a POST method, but when I change the controller mapping to the following

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/user"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dummylogin",
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody UserDTO login(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
        String message = userService.checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(userDTO);
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            userDTO = userService.findByEmailAndPassword(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
            userDTO.setPassword("");
        } else {
            userDTO.setMessage(message);
        }
        return userDTO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String login(){
        return "Hello world";
    }
```

I obtain the following header

```
URL de la requête :http://localhost:8080/api/user/login
Méthode de la requête : GET
Adresse distante : 127.0.0.1:8080
Code d’état :200
```

and the following response

```
Hello world
```

Could you explain why this request is automatically triggered and if I cannot discard this behaviour, how I have to map it on the controller part ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found how to correct the wrong behavior. It was sufficient to add the line

```
.antMatchers("/**/*").permitAll()
```

in

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http         
    .headers()
     .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
     .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/**/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
       .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/api/user/login")
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
           .failureUrl("/")
           .permitAll()
           .and()
       .logout()
```

Adding this line allow an unauthentificated user to access to the requests triggered on the home page and so don't ask the unauthentificated to display the login-form

Considering allowing CORS requests I am still expecting an explaination to understand the difference between SOLUTION1 and SOLUTION2